# Calculate the subtraction of two columns in two dataframes by replacement

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction

I have `df1` which contains:

```
IDs    values
E21    32
DD12   82
K99    222
```

And `df2` that contains:

```
IDs   values
GU1   87
K99   93
E21   48
```

What I need is to check if the `ID` in `df2` exists in `df1`, do the subtraction of the `value` of `df1` - `df2` for that `ID` and update the `value` in `df2`.

If the `ID` of `df2` does not exist in `df1`, the value for that `ID` in `df2` remains the same.

So, the result from the above example (basically `df2` will be updated):

```
IDs    values
GU1    87 #the same not changed since it not exist in df1
K99    129 #exist in df1, do the subtraction 222-93=129
E21    -16 #exist in df1, do the subtraction 32-48=129
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Are the `IDs` in `df1` unique?

Comment: Yes, they are unique @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `update`:

```
df2.update(df1 - df2)
```

Output:

```
     values
IDs        
GU1    87.0
K99   129.0
E21   -16.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# create new column in df2 with name 'new'
df2['new'] = df2['values']
# loop on the values of 'IDs' column
for i, element in enumerate(df2.IDs):
    # condition to check if an element exists in df1  
    if element in df1.IDs.values:
        df2['new'][i]  = df1['values'][df1.index[df1.IDs == element][0]] - df2['values'][i]
# drop the old values column 
df2.drop('values', axis = 1, inplace= True)
# rename the new values column
df2.rename(columns={'new': 'values'}, inplace= True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using pd.merge:

```
# merge the data frames
dfx = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='IDs', how='left', suffixes=('','_2'))

# modify new columns
dfx['val'] = dfx['values_2'] - dfx['values']
dfx['val'] = dfx['val'].combine_first(dfx['values'])
dfx = dfx[['IDs','val']].rename(columns={'val':'values'})

print(dfx)

   IDs  values
0  GU1    87.0
1  K99   129.0
2  E21   -16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
d = df1.set_index('IDs')['values']
i = df2.itertuples(index=False)
df2.assign(values=[d[x] - v if x in d.index else v for x, v in i])

   IDs  values
0  GU1      87
1  K99     129
2  E21     -16
```

---

Same exact idea but using `dict` instead of `pandas.Series`

```
d = dict(zip(df1['IDs'], df1['values']))
i = df2.itertuples(index=False)
df2.assign(values=[d[x] - v if x in d else v for x, v in i])
```